# include a new mixin in all enumerable classes

Tags: ruby, mixins

I'd like to add a module to all Enumerable classes.  Is there a good way to do this?

My solution at this point is:

```
module Enumerable
  include my_module
end

class Array
  include Enumerable
end

class ____
etc...
```

Unless I include the new version of Enumerable in all of the classes which include the original Enumerable, they do not get updated.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Perhaps with some meta programming?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I didn't think that mattered for the question at hand.  But, I'm trying to add a palindrome? method for enumerables for a homework assignment.  I understand that it's silly for things like Hashes, but it's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you have to write the method code inside the `Enumerable` module

```
module Enumerable
    def so
        "StackOverflow!"
    end
end

a = [1, 3, 7]
a.so
#=> "StackOverflow!"
```

Comment: Yep, that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.